# Model field validation in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to validated a custom form field . I have made a model for contact us form . fields are name, subject, email and message . Now user from "DIU" company can contact us only .
email must have '35-' and '@diu.edu.bd' in the email address . How can i validate this email field like this ? Please help

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#module-django.core.validators

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this in your Model:

```
def clean_email(self):
    
    email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
    
    if '@diu.edu.bd' not in email or '35-' not in email:
        raise forms.ValidationError(u'You are not authorized to send us email.')
    
    return email
```

Comment: What did it do?  Any error?  Can you `print()` inside to track?  You have to show code to receive proper help

Comment: can you give me your facebook account or email ? to contact you personally ?